# How to replace array commas with different characters in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, iteration, separator

Given this array `ar` and a list of `separators`:

```
let ar = ["bestes", "haus", "Tiangua"];
const separators = [" ", ""];
```

How can I convert it into a string, while using as separator each  value from the `separators` array, instead of the usual commas?

Expected result:

```
res = ["bestes hausTiangua"]
```

This is my current implementation, but it would use the same separator only.

```
let kw = ar.join(',').replace.(/,/g, '/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in just one operation with the function [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
ar.reduce((a, s, i) => a + separators[i-1] + s)
```

Comment: This is really neat! Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array and shift from the separators every index.

```js
const ar = ["bestes", "haus", "Tiangua"];
const separators = [" ", ""];

let str = ar[0];
for (let i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
  str += separators.shift() + ar[i];
}
console.log(str);
```